# Sequence in Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

[image]

I found out from x1 to x5 but but I am having no idea to find the composite numbers.

Ant help will be truly appreciated.

Comment: HINT: Fix a prime number $p$. Then your sequence is periodic modulo $p$. In particular, if $p$ divides some of the $x_n$, then it divides infinitely many of them: all those must be composite.

Comment: As long as the sequence does not repeat.

Comment: @jyotiprokashroy Where did you get this problem from?

Answer (score 1):

$x$ is invective. There are infinitely many $x_n$.

Suppose that x contains only finitely many composite $x_n$.  Then there exists an $N$ such that $n>N$ implies that $x_n$ is not composite.  Or every, for every $n>N, x_n$ is prime.  If our proposition is false, then when $n$ gets large ever $x_n$ must be a prime number!  If that were the case, it would be a great finding in mathematics.

If a is not co-prime to b, then the gcd(a,b) divide all $x_n$.

I say, that if a and b are co-prime, for all $x_n$, $x_n$ divides some $x_{n+k}$ with $k\leq x_n$, and every $x_{n+mk}$ thereafter.

If $a$ and $b$ are co-prime then $x_n$ is also co-prime to $a$ and $b$.  That is $x_n \equiv b (\mod a)$ and $x_n \equiv a (\mod b)$

$f:\mathbb Z/x_n \to \mathbb Z/x_n, f(y) = ay+b, f$ is a 1-1 function.

$0,b,f(b),f(f(b))...$ forms a cycle of length less than or equal to $x_n$.